# IE Edge: Formatting Issue document.execCommand('inserttext', true, content)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, execcommand

Here is the JS fiddle for this problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/2ds5mor4/1/

Open JS fiddle in chrome and IE Edge.
Paste (ctrl+V) in text area and you will see the text which is not formatted in IE Edge while the same use case works fine in Chrome browsers.

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function(e) {
  var content = "Dear,\r\nIf you love reading books, then we have the best match for your reading choices.\r\nwe have 'The Sunflower Tales' as a \r\ncollection of 40 love poems for you and your loved ones.\r\nAbout our Book:\r\n\r\nThe Sunflower Tales is a collection of Love and Life poems penned down by a young commerce graduate. It isn't about selling a Book, it is more about making a space in the hearts of its reader's with time.";
  e.preventDefault();
  document.execCommand('inserttext', true, content);
});
```

I have used the above function for pasting and predefined the pasting text and inserting using inserttext execCommand.

Can anyone tell me how to keep this formatting?

Comment: You are referring to the line breaks? Those work fine for me in Edge as well.

Comment: The fiddle snippet does nothing in FF, the _aShowDefaultUI_ parameter must be set to `false` to make it work in FF (might help with Edge too?). Notice also, that [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) is obsolete, you can't rely on it working in the future.

Comment: @CBroe - In which edge version you are trying to repro?

Comment: Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1098.0 / Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

Comment: @Teemu - Do you have any alternative of execCommand?

Comment: There's currently not actual alternatives, you've to work with [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) and [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) APIs to achieve something similar. Btw. The fiddle snippet works for me too in Edge 44/18.

Comment: @VinayDhakre,  which exact version you are using for making this test? Let me know about it. I will make a test with it and check the result.

Comment: @CBroe - My version is Microsoft Edge 41.16299.1480.0 / Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299 and it is reproducible in this version.

Comment: Actually, that Edge version seems to be the only browser working correctly with this. HTMLDivElement doesn't normally show new-line characters as new-lines, you'd need to show a div with `white-space: pre-wrap;` set to show the actual new-lines. This might also make your code to work as you want it to work in Edge 41 too ...

Comment: ... or `pre-line` if the extra white-space matters, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: @Teemu pre-line/pre-wrap is not working for me.

Comment: @Teemu My bad, pre-wrap worked for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Teemu, I suggest you post your suggestion as an answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the issue with MS Edge 42.17134.1098.0 and I find that it gave the same result as Chrome.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function(e) {
  var content = "Dear,\r\nIf you love reading books, then we have the best match for your reading choices.\r\nwe have 'The Sunflower Tales' as a \r\ncollection of 40 love poems for you and your loved ones.\r\nAbout our Book:\r\n\r\nThe Sunflower Tales is a collection of Love and Life poems penned down by a young commerce graduate. It isn't about selling a Book, it is more about making a space in the hearts of its reader's with time.";
  e.preventDefault();
  document.execCommand('inserttext', true, content);
});

});
</script>
<style>
div[contenteditable] {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
}

div[contenteditable]:hover {
    background: #ff0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div contenteditable="true">
  Paste here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See my testing result here.

[image]

I suggest you make a test again and check the result.

Comment: My version is Microsoft Edge 41.16299.1480.0 / Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299 and it is reproducible in this version.